# Fixed width but variable background with CSS3

Tags: html, css

Sometimes, I need to restrict section of a page to a fixed width. But the background should extend all the available space.

With CSS2 I used to do something like this (jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fniwes/wwVp4/)

css:

```
#container { background-color: #ddd; }
#content { width: 300px; margin: 0 auto; }
```

html:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="content">All the content inside container should be limited to 300px but the background should cover all the screen width</div>
</div>
```

The content here is just a plain text, but it is usually something more complex.

Is there a better way to accomplish the same result without the extra #content tag? I don't mind using CSS3 or something that is only supported by Chrome or Firefox.

Just for clarification. I want to remove #content tag. I want the markup to be

```
<div id="container">
    All the content bla bla
</div>
```

(and I want to style no tag other than #container.. maybe it is not possible, but maybe there is something new in CSS3 or other proposal that I don't know)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the calc() function in css3, you can use that like this:

```
#container { background-color: #ddd; padding-left: calc(50% - 150px); padding-right:calc(50% - 150px);}
```

Comment: Good solution! And calc() is supported in most browsers: http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc, but sometimes the -webkit- prefix is needed.

Answer (score 0):

is there any specific reason you are against using a container div? You could do:

```
#content { background-color: #ddd; width: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 50%; }
```

But I wouldn't reccomend it and the best solution is still to use containers

Comment: The reason is because I want to learn better ways to do things that sometimes are constraints because technological reasons, and others just plain ignorance. Actually I use containers but every time that I have to add a tag just for layout purposes I feel that I am doing something wrong. (specially when the same issue happens several times in different projects). Btw. your solution do not keeps a 300px width, it just makes the content start in the middle of the container.

Comment: Yeah I'm aware of that, that's because to my knowledge there is no way to create a div that will stretch 100% but also constrain the content inside to a fixed pixel width. There is nothing wrong with using extra divs as containers, it's not bad practice.